# Adding values of dynamic fields

Tags: javascript

I have been looking for a way to multiply the values of two dynamically created text fields. I found that using the following as a client side JS function. The total_inv_items_field is a hidden field that increments as the dynamic elements are created I use that value to control the for loop:

```
    function calcTotals()
    {
       var totalinvcitems = document.getElementById('total_inv_items_field').value;
       var currinvcitem = 0;
       var invoice_total_value = 0;

       for (var invcitemcounter=0; invcitemcounter<totalinvcitems; invcitemcounter++)
       {
          currinvcitem = currinvcitem + 1;

          var quantity = document.getElementById('qty' + currinvcitem).value;
          var price = document.getElementById('cost' + currinvcitem).value;
          var totallineitem = quantity * price;
          document.getElementById('totallinefee' + currinvcitem).value = totallineitem;
          invoice_total_value = invoice_total_value + totallineitem;
       }
       document.getElementById('invoice_total').value = invoice_total_value;
    }
```

Every thing up to the second to last line of the for loop works. The dynamically created multiplication is working. My hurdle I cannot figure out is how to get the variable "invoice_total_value" to be the value of the invoice_total form component. It never updates. I tried to parseFloat the numbers being added and tried parseFloating the invoice_total_value sum variable too. I also thought it may have been a type conversion issue so I tried adding a null ('') string to it to convert it to a string and then assign it. Nothing has worked. I just cannot reassign that to a static text field. Any ideas? I am getting a migraine... ;)

Comment: Why have you included the PHP tag, nothing in your example is PHP relevant

Comment: would you be able to use libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: is there any errors in the browser console

Comment: also share the html markup if possible

Answer (score 0):

if your element with id `invoice_total` is not input field, then do:

```
document.getElementById('invoice_total').innerHTML = invoice_total_value;
```

Comment: OK I feel dumb... My issue was the id field of my form item had different quotes ' & ".